How can I know the lengths of an ellipsoid without plotting them using eigen values
I have 3 parameters: A, B and C with 20000 data each of them. When I put them together in an 3D graph, they form a dot cloud with A in X axis, B in Y axis and C in Z axis. I want to fix this dots cloud in an 90% covariance error ellipsoid and determine the lengths, i.e. width, height and stretch, in > 1000 samples individually. Width will be in X axis, height in Y axis and stretch in Z axis). So, for each sample:
1) I calculate the covariation matrix with var()
covMat <- var(cbind(A,B,C)) 
covMat
           A          B          C
A 0.08269010 0.05330448 0.05329601
B 0.05330448 0.33033311 0.14017367
C 0.05329601 0.14017367 0.18732865

2) I calculate the eigenvalues with eigen()
evals<-eigen(covMat)$values
evals
[1] 0.43162433 0.10861830 0.06010923

#I obtain 3 eigenvalues ordered from largest-to-smallest
3) I determine the lengths of the 90% covariance error ellipsoid
ell.len <- 2*sqrt(6.251*evals)
ell.len
[1] 2.971533 1.666728 1.325708

The tricky thing: Since eigenvalues are always in a decreasing order, how can I know which number of the ell.len correspond to each length (width, height and stretch) since sometimes height can be larger than width and stretch, and other combinations. I want to know this because I would like to determine numerically when the ellipsoids are prolate (Height > Width > Stretch), oblate (Width > Height > Stretch) or spherical (Width = Height = Stretch) in each sample (n = 1000).

This is much clearer than your last question (thank you), but I'm still a little confused. You suggest that 'width' corresponds to the extent along the X-axis. As far as I can tell the clearest definition of that would be sd(A). Once you compute the eigenvalues there is (again) no way that I can think of to identify a principal dimension of the ellipsoid with a particular axis ... ???  (in your example you say that prolate and oblate both correspond to "height > width > stretch" - is one of these a typo?)

Following the definitions on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid I would say that the definitions of "oblate" and "prolate" are only clear when two of the eigenvalues are equal and the ellipsoid is thus a spheroid: oblate corresponds to e1 = e2 > e3; prolate corresponds to e1 > e2 = e3. Again, more context for where your definitions come from would be useful.

Thank you very much for your comment @Ben Bolker. Actually what you suggest related to sd(A) was my plan B. By adding this previous step, I can be a bit more sure which number of the ell.len correspond to each length of the ellipsoid. Thank you.

You could bypass the eigen function and just use
evals <- .Internal(La_rs(covMat, TRUE))$values

since the covMat matrix is symmetric.

Thank you both very much for your answers. However, this solution only gives me the eigenvalues in increasing order for all samples. For most of the samples, the largest eigenvalue corresponds to C, on the Z axis. However, for the other two lengths (width and height), identifying which eigenvalue corresponds to the X or Y axis is more difficult, as the eigenvalues are quite similar. I guess I will have to individually check these samples and invert their width and height.
